# Vortex and Anti-Vortex Pairs that form below the Berezinskii-Kosterlitz-Thouless transition and Abrikosov Vortices in superconductors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, superconductivity, topology

Please forgive me for my naivety of the subject, as I am relatively new and this is my first question as well. I am currently quite confused about Abrikosov vortices and Vortex and Anti-Vortex Pairs that form below the Berezinskii-Kosterlitz-Thouless transition Temperature in 2-D superconductors and their properties and differences. Basically, I understand how each of them form in that simply Abrikosov vortices occur when external magnetic fields penetrate the material, whilst vortex-antivortex pairs arise in the BKT transition in two-dimensional systems as topological defects, binding together to create order at low temperatures but unbinding due to thermal fluctuations at higher temperatures. But, I am confused about how their physical properties compare. For example the core size of an Abrikosov vortex is roughly the coherence length but I do not know the core size of the vortex and anti-vortex pairs. Do the pairs have some discrete magnetic flux quantum like fluxon?  Is it possible to image the pairs like can be done with the Abrikosov vortices or do they not last long enough for that? And finally in say a high temperature superconductor like the cuprates which likely have a 2-D mechanism, do they actually coexist at ultra low temperatures with an applied magnetic field above HC1 or does the application of any magnetic field stop them all together? Thanks and sorry the question is long, but would really appreciate any clarifications as well.

Comment: For anyone interested I found this paper which examined vortex-antivortex pairs in a 2-D ferromagnet https://journals.jps.jp/doi/10.7566/JPSJ.90.014702 using TEM so I am guessing it must be possible to image them. There is also this paper that did something similar https://journals.jps.jp/doi/pdf/10.7566/JPSJNC.18.01 I also did not realise there are also quantum anamolous vortices which exist too and are different again. Finally there is this paper which imaged the spontaneous vortex-antivortex pairs formation when cooling https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.247002

Comment: If anyone could clarify anything even what all these different types of vortices are that would be great as I am so very lost and confused